# Changing color of a string in listbox - MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a list of names in a listbox. What I would like to do is have a certain selected name change color, from red to green, when I click a button.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported officially. There are non-documented features that do it - check out http://www.undocumentedmatlab.com.

Answer (score 1):

You might have already solved this, but I thought I would clarify Andrey just a bit. MATLAB GUI components can handle HTML in their properties. So, I imagine setting up your button callback to edit the properties of your listbox using HTML to change the color would be an appropriate way to proceed here. Yair Altman has a pretty good write up here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/html-support-in-matlab-uicomponents/

Granted, that example is simple, but you should be able to adapt it to fit your needs if I have understood your question correctly.